# Is there any existing foundation to study semiotics from topological viewpoint?

Tags: general-topology, reference-request

I'm currently delving into the semiotics from the school of Saussure. On the course, I found that there is some correlation between semiotics and topology based on categorical demands

(Edit: I conjectured this relationship based on the empirical assumption of the well addressed "topological semantics" in the field of artificial intelligence. The relation between semantics and semiotics might seem straightforward: semantics is the study of the meaning and reference of linguistic expressions, while semiotics is the general study of signs of all kinds and in all their aspects. Semiotics comprises semantics as a part, along with syntax and pragmatics. The categorical underpinning is pretty obvious)

But I couldn't find any existing academic synthesis of topological semiotics. Could anyone suggest any(or cohesive) theoretical framework to cling on to this fascinating subject?

Comment: What are those 'categorical demands'?

Comment: @Berci Basically, category theory is the main conceptual framework that inclined me to see the correlation between topology and semiotics. It's a powerful language which allows us to see the universal components of a family of structures of a given kind. In semiotics, pierce and Saussure used the category theory to  find the mappings between sign and the sign system.

Comment: You should add references supporting your conjecture. I suspect, however, that the analogy is not with topology but with the Category Theory, which  is a separate branch of mathematics.